# Java Files.Copy deleting content of first file

Tags: java

The files.write succesfully writes the "test" strings into test1.txt.
But after the files.copy is executed the content of "test1.txt" gets deleted and "text2.txt" contains the content of "test1.txt".
The problem is that I want to keep the content of test1.txt.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\trist\\Downloads\\test1.txt");
Path path2 = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\trist\\Downloads\\test2.txt");

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("test");
strings.add("test");

Files.write(path,strings,Charset.defaultCharset(),StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
Files.Copy(path, path2, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Works fine for me, sorry. (Java 9.0.1, Windows 10)

Comment: You could try a small sleep between the write and the copy in case there's some buffering issue, or the file is held open by some other process e.g. your virus checker (on a text fle?), but I can't see why that would be needed, or you could see the sequence of filesystem API class using SysInternals ProcMon, although you'd have to wade through a lot of other API calls.

Comment: Works fine in Java 10 on Mac OSX

Comment: God @snr who uses Java 10? I'm still stuck on Java 8.

Comment: @SamOrozco ready for 11 ?? ((: http://www.java-countdown.xyz/

Comment: Are you sure you’re using [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) and not something like [Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29)?  The code you’ve posted clearly is not the actual code you’re running, since there is no Files.Copy method (with an uppercase ‘C’).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe change where it says `REPLACE_EXISTING` to `COPY_ATTRIBUTES`